# Convert XY Values to RGB

Tags: android, philips-hue

I am using the Android Philips Hue SDK and I am currently having an issue with converting the light bulbs XY value to RGB.

I have looked at [this code](http://www.developers.meethue.com/content/phutilitiescalculatergbfromxy) provided in a forum on Philips Hue website and the code has been provided by someone from Hue Support.

I have the following function using this code from the forum:

```
public static int[] convertXYToRGB(float[] xy, String lightModel)
    {
        int color = PHUtilities.colorFromXY(xy, lightModel);
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);
        return new int[] {r, g, b};
    }
```

And I am calling it like:

```
int hue = lightState.getHue();
float[] xy = PHUtilities.calculateXY(hue, item.light.getModelNumber());

int[] rgb = Utilities.convertXYToRGB(xy, item.light.getModelNumber());
```

Looking at the RGB value I get back it seems to be the wrong colour. For example, using the official app, I set one of my light bulbs to red. When I run my app, the RGB value that comes back is a pale yellow.

Has anyone else experienced this or know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue while programming a desktop application using the same [Java SDK](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/java-multi-platform-and-android-sdk) *(login required)*. Interestingly, a plain red turned into a fade yellow, exactly how you describe it. A possible solution is to use the xy-values directly instead of the conversion from hue-values. That finally solved the problem for me. You can get the xy-values from the `PHLightState` object using the methods `.getX()` and `.getY()`. After that, use `colorFromXY` as in your code to get the RGB-values ([as android color value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) = `int`).

```
PHLightState s = light.getLastKnownLightState();

float xy[] = new float[] {s.getX(), s.getY()};
int combRGB = PHUtilities.colorFromXY(xy, light.getModelNumber());
```

On Android, convert `combRGB` as you already do. Make sure to include `android.graphics.Color`. If you are testing on non-Android systems you can use the following code:

```
Color theColor = new Color(combRGB);
int[] sepRGB = {theColor.getRed(), theColor.getGreen(), theColor.getBlue()};
```

**Note:** The lights can only address a certain color gamut depending on the type. This is explained into detail [here](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/core-concepts#color_gets_more_complicated). The 'normal' bulbs with a color gamut *B* have quite some limitations. For example: most greens turn into yellows and the blues contain a certain amount of red.

**Example values:** The following overall conversions are tested on my live system with LCT001-blubs. I used `PHUtilities.calculateXYFromRGB()` to convert the input, then I set the xy-values of the new light state with `.setX()` and `.setY()` and finally sent it to the bridge. The values are then extracted from the light cache in the application as soon as it gets the next update.

```
255   0   0   ->   254   0   0
  0 255   0   ->   237 254   0
  0   0 255   ->    90   0 254
200   0 200   ->   254   0 210
255 153   0   ->   254 106   0
255 153 153   ->   254  99 125
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I don't understand why Philips haven't got a conversion utility as they do it in one direction, why not convert back as well. bit odd